# Output a 2D array in rows/columns

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, console

Basically, I have a 2D string array holding names in one dimension, and a set of grades in the other. As best as I can describe it, I would like the output to be with names as "headers" with the grades for each going down that column.

As such:

```
Name1 Name2
83    47
66    22
```

etc.

My code is as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create a 2D array for names, and their grades
        string[,] studentGrades = new string[5, 8];

        // Set student names/grades manually
        studentGrades[0, 0] = "Steve";
        studentGrades[0, 1] = "69";
        studentGrades[0, 2] = "80";
        studentGrades[0, 3] = "66";
        studentGrades[0, 4] = "75";
        studentGrades[0, 5] = "90";
        studentGrades[0, 6] = "69";
        studentGrades[0, 7] = "98";

        studentGrades[1, 0] = "Bob";
        studentGrades[1, 1] = "73";
        studentGrades[1, 2] = "67";
        studentGrades[1, 3] = "65";
        studentGrades[1, 4] = "91";
        studentGrades[1, 5] = "48";
        studentGrades[1, 6] = "33";
        studentGrades[1, 7] = "94";

        studentGrades[2, 0] = "Lewis";
        studentGrades[2, 1] = "67";
        studentGrades[2, 2] = "80";
        studentGrades[2, 3] = "66";
        studentGrades[2, 4] = "75";
        studentGrades[2, 5] = "90";
        studentGrades[2, 6] = "69";
        studentGrades[2, 7] = "63";

        studentGrades[3, 0] = "Sara";
        studentGrades[3, 1] = "55";
        studentGrades[3, 2] = "58";
        studentGrades[3, 3] = "63";
        studentGrades[3, 4] = "70";
        studentGrades[3, 5] = "55";
        studentGrades[3, 6] = "55";
        studentGrades[3, 7] = "76";

        studentGrades[4, 0] = "Xavier";
        studentGrades[4, 1] = "22";
        studentGrades[4, 2] = "27";
        studentGrades[4, 3] = "25";
        studentGrades[4, 4] = "19";
        studentGrades[4, 5] = "42";
        studentGrades[4, 6] = "18";
        studentGrades[4, 7] = "32";

        // Loop the array dimensions and output/format output the names/grades
        for (int name = 0; name < studentGrades.GetLength(0); name++)
        {
            for (int grade = 0; grade < studentGrades.GetLength(1); grade++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(studentGrades[name, grade]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
```

### Edit

The output is as such:

```
Steve
69
80
....

Bob
73
67
....
```

etc

Comment: Does your code work? Why not? What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: I guess I should have included that. It runs, but the output is in a fully top-down manner. Will update post with example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int grade = 0; grade < studentGrades.GetLength(1); grade++)
{
    for (int name = 0; name < studentGrades.GetLength(0); name++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0, -15}", studentGrades[name, grade]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The code above will give this result:

```
Steve          Bob            Lewis          Sara           Xavier
69             73             67             55             22
80             67             80             58             27
66             65             66             63             25
75             91             75             70             19
90             48             90             55             42
69             33             69             55             18
98             94             63             76             32
```

Comment: What does the -15 do? I know {0} is basically an insertion point.

Comment: It's used to align the text in the console output: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ahh, I think I understand now from reading the link a bit and then testing. So, it adds spacing between each element in the inner loop that loops through the names, and then in the outer loop the grades are shaved to a new line, conforming to the spacing applied to the names. Am I on the right track with my thinking?

Comment: The inner loop prints both the names and the grades. The -15 thing (but you could also use 15 to align all to right instead of left) ensures that the columns will be aligned no matter the length of the names or the length of the grades. The alignment won't work if you write a name/grade longer than 15 chars.